# ggplot in Python is not identical to R version

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I am trying to make ggplot working in Python (iPython) by simply translating working example from R. However, I am receiving a lot of warnings/errors. After some fiddling, I got graph produced, but it ended as completely different for the one made in R. Here is the R code:

```
require(ggplot2)

example = read.table('exampleData.txt', header=TRUE, sep='\t')

ggplot(data=example, aes(x=case, y=H, fill=factor(type))) +
    geom_bar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=0.5, 
        binwidth=0.5, stat='identity') +
    scale_x_discrete('Case') +
    scale_y_continuous('H')
```

This produces nice figure:

[image: ggplot figure in R]

However, I cannot get the same in Python. After too many error messages, I've produced something completely different from the above figure. Here is the Python code:

```
from itertools import izip, chain, product
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ggplot import *

example = pd.DataFrame(np.genfromtxt('exampleData.txt', names=True, dtype=None))

print ggplot(aes(x='case', y='H', fill='factor(type)'), data=example) +\
    geom_bar()
```

Please, can you help me with this? Also, is there anything comprehensive on plotting in Python? Also, some comparative howto for ggplot in R and Python?

Comment: please provide output of `dput(example)` from R console

Comment: From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ggplot: "TODO: The list is long, but distinguished." More likely you will a a lot of things that do not work directly ;)